# Grafana Iframe howto

Tags: android, iframe, grafana

I'm new here and new to programming on Android Studio. But I also have experience under PLC.

I would just like to have an Iframe from Grafana displayed in an app for a project. On my website everything works with this IFrame under SSL.
In the app, things for MQTT are already specified and work. I have been reading the internet for  many days now. But i don't find the mistake. I suspect it is because of the cookie for Grafana. I only get an error message from Grafana in the IFrame. The Config.ini should not be correct. But an other website as IFrame come without errors? The Iframe (Grafana) runs through a proxy. I myself suspect that it is due to my app itself. It can be called up correctly anywhere in Chrome or Firefox.

Here the error inside the IFrame:

> If you're seeing this Grafana has faild to load its application files
>
> 1. caused by your proxy settings
> 2. make sure your grafanaini settings includes subpath
> 3. if you have a local dev build make sure you buildfrontend using ;yarn start
> 4. Sometimes restarting grafana-server can help

Here my AndroidManifest in Android Studio:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    package="com.Manuxxx.xxx">
    <dist:module dist:instant="true" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService" >
        </service>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Here is the code I try to display the IFrame and currently only the error message from Grafana is coming (the IFrame Web-Adress is here not right!):

```
val myWebView: WebView = root.findViewById(R.id.GrafRoom)

myWebView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        myWebView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
        myWebView.settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true
        myWebView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
        myWebView.settings.allowFileAccess = true
        myWebView.settings.allowContentAccess = true
        myWebView.settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true)
        myWebView.settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        myWebView.settings.userAgentString = ("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.137 Safari/537.36")
        //myWebView.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()

CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true)
CookieManager.getInstance().acceptThirdPartyCookies(myWebView)

val path =
            "<iframe src='https://server.manuxxx.xxx/d-solo/oPKo9C9Wz/apartment-test?orgId=1&from=1586083942562&to=1586256742563&panelId=8' width='100%' height='100%' style='border: none;'></iframe>"

myWebView.loadData(path, "text/html", "utf-8")
```

Grafana keeps getting an error message. The Iframes from Grafana run on a different website. No matter which browser or device. I can also display Iframes from another website in my app.  Only from my Grafana in my app does not run in the app. Has somebody any idea?